# Apache2 on virtual server without root permission

Tags: apache-http-server

I am trying to install Apache2 on a virtual server. I installed apr, apr-util and pcre.

Then when trying to install apache, the ./configure thing work but when i try to make I get this error: libtool: link: cannot find the library /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la' or unhandled argument/usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la'

To configure I typed this: ./configure --prefix=/data/home/afora001/php-apache/apache/ --with-apr=/data/home/afora001/php-apache/apr/ --with-apr-util=/data/home/afora001/php-apache/apru/ --with-pcre=/data/home/afora001/php-apache/pcre/

I don't get why it's trying to find a library in /usr?

Thanks! What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install the "-dev" variants of those packages.  Reading the install guide in apache provides the following insight: "On some platforms, you may have to install the corresponding -dev packages to allow httpd to build against your installed copy of APR and APR-Util."

Comment: Where did you read that? And where can i find those? I don't see any -dev packages here http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: Well, I assumed when you stated that you "installed apr, apr-util and pcre" that you used your OS's package manager to do so.  If you did, you would need to install the "-dev" variant of those packages.  If you didn't and you compiled from source, then you need to do the following: "Make sure you have APR and APR-Util already installed on your system. If you don't, or prefer to not use the system-provided versions, download the latest versions of both APR and APR-Util from Apache APR, unpack them into ./srclib/apr and ./srclib/apr-util and use ./configure's --with-included-apr option."

Comment: All this information is found in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html under Requirements.

Comment: You are right, I don't know how I did not see that. It seems to be working now. Thanks

Comment: I copied and pasted the comment as the answer, please accept.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assumed when you stated that you "installed apr, apr-util and pcre" that you used your OS's package manager to do so. If you did, you would need to install the "-dev" variant of those packages. If you didn't and you compiled from source, then you need to do the following: "Make sure you have APR and APR-Util already installed on your system. If you don't, or prefer to not use the system-provided versions, download the latest versions of both APR and APR-Util from Apache APR, unpack them into ./srclib/apr and ./srclib/apr-util and use ./configure's --with-included-apr option."

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  Please tick the check next to my answer, greatly appreciated.